# Is there possible to pass text from python to node js?

Tags: python, html, node.js

I am new to python and node js. I have an task that python should communicate with node.js. Here i just want pass one text from python to node js communication using html page and as well as media. Need enter input through android and then wanted to pass through python to node js. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Create a web service and communicate via REST between them ?

Comment: I didnt get clarify

Comment: You will need to setup 'Flask' in Python to serve up the endpoint and 'Request' in node to ask the end point for the text,

Comment: Can i get some examples on that?

Comment: How should i pass the text value through above communication?